# Matrix (plot) -  Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have 5 matrix c

```
for w in range(len(nR)):
    c = dot(U2, nR[w])
```

Output:

```
c[1 2]  
c[3 4]  
c[2 5]  
c[4 1]  
c[2 2]
```

Note: c is a dot product of two matrix, U2 and nR

I try to assign

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
    x = c[0]  
    y = c[1]  
    plt.scatter(x,y)  
    plt.show()
```

but only one point plotted. I tried to do for loop but seems not working.

Please guide me on this. Thanks!

Comment: You say '5 matrix C' and then give something which is not valid Python. What is `C`? Also note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends reserving `CapWords` for classes, and using `lowercase_with_underscores` for local variables.

Comment: It is 5 different matrices, which will be treated as coordinate(x,y).

Comment: So what does this have to do with factorization?

Comment: That's not how python works. `c` can only hold one value, and the notation you have provided doesn't make sense in Python. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: Yes, the output is from the dot product of two matrix. I put it in the range(len(nR)) so U2 will perform dot product with nR[1],nR[2],..nR[w]. and also U2 is 2x5,nR[] is 5x1 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose `c` is your list of coordinates:

```
c = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 5), (4, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Then you do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[i[0] for i in c]
y=[i[1] for i in c]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The list `x` contains your x values, and `y` contains your y values.

Comment: Thanks! Another question is, if I want to extract 'c' straight from the 'for loop' generated, in other words, without initialize c based on the output. Is there any way to assign the matrices generated into a list? Sorry, I'm newbie. :)

Comment: There is invalid python in your code. For example, python output can't be like `c[1 2]`. Also, there _cannot_ be any output to your program in the first place as you're not printing anything. What is the form of `c`? Please put more detail before we can try to help you.